# How to calculate column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have a table that contains the id, name and age of a person as an int, for instance 20.
I have to create a select that gets the name, age, and year of birth. How can I calculate this?

So far I have this, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT name, age, CURRENT_YEAR-age as yearOfBirth
FROM person;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be storing the age, but the date of birth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT 
  name, 
  age, 
  extract(year from current_date) - age as yearOfBirth
FROM person;
```

Comment: Ok, I was born at `2000-12-12` (year of birth = 2000), Today is 2020 and I still 19 years old. `2020-19 = 2001`. IMO there is no good answer for this question.

Comment: @Abelisto I know what you mean, it is impossible to get the exact age, but the answer given below works just fine for what I need